# Data scraping with Python and Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, python-2.x

I am currently making my first steps with Python & Beautiful Soup in order to scrape data from the Russian statistics website.

Looking at different examples here on Stack Overflow, I think the code is correct, and yet my simple query does not return anything from this site. When executing the code, my Python command line remains blank, but also does not return an error.

What's wrong here?

My (very simple) code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
url = "http://www.gks.ru/bgd/free/B00_25/IssWWW.exe/Stg/d000/000715.HTM"
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
print(soup)
```

Comment: Instead of urllib2, try using `requests` and a simple `requests.get(url)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to specify a parser:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), 'html.parser')
```

Comment: *you need to specify a parser* . parser is optional but good to pass in so I don't think that is the problem here. btw OP's code works for me.

Comment: it works even without warnings if i specify a parser

Comment: May I ask what you see as output from the print function when you run the code? I don't see anything after that print statement...

Comment: Hmm... I use Enthought Canopy and I'm not seeing any output whatsoever, which is very confusing. Do you have any advice on how I can fix this on my end? I do see output if I paste any other link into the above code...

Comment: i would recommend to use pure latest python and command line for small tasks and pycharm for bigger